# Ring of Integers $\mathcal{O}_{K}$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $\{b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{d}\}$ be a basis of a Number field $K$. Then if the $b_{i}$ are in $\mathcal{O}_{K}$, the discriminant of $K$ relative to $\{b_{1},b_{2},\dots,b_{d}\}$ is an integer. In the proof they say that if $b_{i}b_{j}$ is an algebraic integer, then the $Tr(b_{i}b_{j})$ is an integer. I don't understand why this is. (Tr means trace)

Comment: Every algebraic integer has integer trace. This is a very standard fact in number theory.

Comment: The trace of an algebraic integer $\alpha$ is the coefficient of $x^{n-1}$ in the minimal polynomial of $\alpha$, if the minimal polynomial has degree $n$. Therefore it is an integer.

Comment: One should be careful here. Essentially you are right but in the definition of the trace the field $K$ plays a crucial rule. E.g. The algebraic integer $a:=\sqrt{2}+1$ has trace $2$ in the field $\mathbb{Q}(a)$ but trace $4$ if considered as an element of $\mathbb{Q}(a,\sqrt{3})$. Nevertheless your argument is valid since the trace is an integral multiple of the coefficient you mentioned.

Comment: How did you define trace?